# Solr query not returning expected results

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have a solr query like: `host:8983/solr/collection/select?q=propids%3A1&wt=json&indent=true`
where i filter about propids: 1. The problem is when filter propids:1 and 2, i only have documents indexed with propids: 1, buuut I get all the indexed results when using with and, even if I don't have any propids having 2. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: With Solr, you're going to have to provide much more information. Include your schema design (the fields in schema.xml) as well as the definition of your request handler (the "/select" reference) from solrconfig.xml.

Comment: I need docs with propids 1 and 2, it is a multiValued field, values separated by ",". These will be properties for some products like capacity and power or whatever property. Each product has a capacity property a power property, etc. When I`m building my filters I have to build my query so if a type of capacity is selected it should return all prods with that property, than if another prop is selected it should return prods having the first AND the second property. Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: "I need docs with propids 1 and 2, it is a multiValued field, values separated by "," -- can you show your schema field definition and a sample document you have indexed?

Comment: Field: `<field name="propids" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>`
Doc ex: [doc](http://en.textsave.org/U8N)

Comment: Thanks, but the doc link shows a query result, not a document used to populate your search index.

Comment: It is populated with data-importer from mysql. How would you like to see it?

Comment: So when you query just one propids, you get what you want, but when you use 'and', things go wrong. Show us the and-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All results which contain propids = 1

```
host:8983/solr/collection/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&fq=propids:1
```

All results which contain propids = 2

```
host:8983/solr/collection/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&fq=propids:2
```

All results which contains either propids = 1 or propids = 2

```
host:8983/solr/collection/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&fq=propids:(1 OR 2)
```

All results which contains both propids = 1 and propids = 2

```
host:8983/solr/collection/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&fq=propids:1&fq=propids:2
```

Comment: It seems ok, unfortunately I can not test it anymore because I have already modified logic. I think this is the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your query part is

> q=propids:1 and 2

This doesn't mean it'll search propids=1 and 2.

Please check your **solrconfig.xml** for the default search field.
Because if your query is like I mentioed, then it means

> q=propids:1 and default_searchable_field:2

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get documents with propids=1 plus documents with propids=2, do this.

```
q=propids:1 2
```

This will match both words (1 and 2) with the contents of the field and get both types of documents.

Comment: Note: this assumes a default query operator of OR.